# Suppose $a,b$ are real numbers and $0 < a < b$. Prove $ba^n + ab^n < a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}$

Tags: proof-verification, inequality

> $a,b$ are real numbers and $0 < a < b$
>
> Prove that for all $n ≥ 1$, $ba^n + ab^n < a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}$

My attempt:

By contradiction. Suppose

$$\tag{* }ba^n + ab^n ≥ a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}$$

Rearranging $(*)$ gives

$$\begin{align}
0 & ≥ a^{n+1} + b^{n+1} - ba^n - ab^n \\
  & ≥ a^{n+1} - ba^n + b^{n+1} - ab^n \\
  & ≥ a^n(a - b) - b^{n}(a - b) \\
  & ≥ (a - b)(a^n - b^n)
\end{align}$$

But since $0 < a < b$, we have $(a-b) < 0$ and $(a^n - b^n) < 0$, and thus  $(a-b)(a^n - b^n) > 0$.

Hence a contradiction. $\Box$

1. Is it correct?
2. Is there a better way? (Preferably direct proof)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. But it is more natural to apply the *same* idea to get a direct proof:$$a^{n+1}+b^{n+1}-ba^n-ab^n=(b^n-a^n)(b-a)>0.$$

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Rearrangement inequality](https://brilliant.org/wiki/rearrangement-inequality/):
$$0<a<b \Rightarrow 0<a^n<b^n\\
ba^n + ab^n < b\cdot b^n +a\cdot a^n=a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}.$$

Comment: second step is not clear