# Proving $ab^n + ba^n < a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}$ by Induction

Tags: induction

Given $0<a<b , ab \in \mathbb{R}$ , $n \geq 1$

By induction, Assuming $ab^n + ba^n < a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}$.    -  $(1)$

To prove $ab^{n+1} + ba^{n+1} < a^{n+2} + b^{n+2}$

Multiplying (1) by ab we get

$a^2b^{n+1} + b^2a^{n+1} < a^{n+2}b + b^{n+2}a$

How to proceed ?

Thanks

Comment: What  are $a,b,n?$  Why do you want to prove it by induction? Can you write a context - where does the problem come from?

Comment: @user376343 yeah i forgot. i edited question now

Comment: If the inequality $a^nb+ab^n < aa^n + bb^n$ is true (which is already answered below) for $0<a<b, ab \in \mathbb{R}, n<0$, why do you want to prove it by induction? If you multiply it with $ab$ which is constant and positive, the fact remains the same. It is like, $a>b \Leftrightarrow 2a>2b$ which does not make sense.

Comment: @EddyPiedad because it is question from chapter named mathematical induction

Comment: I agree with the first comment. You should provide the context. Maybe you can cite your book reference in your question. And also, you still need to define $n$. Your assumption in (1) is only valid for $n<0$ as shown in the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose $a,b$ are real numbers and $0 &lt; a &lt; b$. Prove $ba^n + ab^n &lt; a^{n+1} + b^{n+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439086/suppose-a-b-are-real-numbers-and-0-a-b-prove-ban-abn-an1-b) . Found using [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24ab%5En%20%2B%20ba%5En%20%3C%20a%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%2B%20b%5E%7Bn%2B1%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: Your edit @SophieClad is valid given that $n>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation is equivalent to
$$0 < aa^n-a^nb-ab^n+bb^n$$
$$0 < (a-b)(a^n-b^n)$$

Since $0 < a < b,$ where $ a,b \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$0>(a-b)$$

that leaves
$$0 > (a^n-b^n)$$

Working on $n$, we have
$$(a^n-b^n) < 0$$
$$n\ln\frac{a}{b} < 0.$$

Again, $\ln\frac{a}{b}<0$ when $a<b$ so
$$n > 0.$$

Comment: It doesn't really matter $a<b$

Comment: Thanks but i would like to proceed from where i left if possible'

Comment: You should define $n$. And here you can see what the value of $n$ should be.

Comment: @EddyPiedad yes i have edited. can it be solved from where i left or this is only way that you wrote ?

Comment: Yes @SophieClad. I have also edited and modified the typo.  It should be true for all $n>0$.